# Node js : Entry into the error block only

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

This is my app.js generated by express js while installing:

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("coming to this use func");
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log("Dev request sent");
    console.log(err.message);
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: err
  });
 });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.log("testing this function");
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
  message: err.message,
  error: {}
  });
 });

// I wrote this code to detect '127.0.0.1:3000/enter' in the url     
// correspondingly fetches questions from the database
app.post('/enter', function(req, res, next) {
console.log("Coming here.");
connection.query('SELECT * from questions_table', function(err, rows, fields) {
if (!err) {
  console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
  var myData = JSON.stringify(rows);
  res.render('display', {myData:rows })
 }
else {
  console.log('Error while performing Query.');
  res.render('display', { title: 'The index page!'})
  } 
 });
});
```

The control never comes to the chunk that I wrote, rather it gets into the if loop that says :

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development')
```

ALWAYS and throws some error. Front end is a mere form submission. What am I doing wrong here? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, so let's do some debugging: [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.settings.table) tells us that `app.get('env')` is *supposed* to say "development", unless you explicitly set or override it. Did you?

Comment: No, I havent overriden it

Comment: then we've found part of the problem. the `app.use` function gets bound, and throws an error: remove all the code around it, because it doesn't contribute to the problem, and then see which line things are going wrong on. Keep removing parts that seem to not contribute until the problem's suddenly go. The part you removed is the real problem. This is an exercise you should *always* do, because usually it lets you find the problem all on your own, instead of needing something like stackoverflow.

Comment: Your 404 handler should go after your route, not before. Swap the order of the routes and you should get the desired behavior

Comment: Found the problem. Yes, route must be in front of the error handlers. Thanks